# A question regarding the validity of the Union Axiom

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the book "Elements of Set Theory" by Enderton, the union of an infinite collection of sets is described this way on pg.23:

> Suppose we have the infinite collection of sets $A=\{b_0,b_1,b_2,\dots\}$, and we want to take the union of all $b_i$. Then we have a define a new axiom: the **Union Axiom**. It states that for any set $A$, there exists a set $B$ such that $$\forall x[x\in B\iff (\exists b\in A)x\in b]$$

Before this, regarding unions, we had only the **Pairing Axiom**, which says that for any two sets $u,v$, there exists the set $\{u,v\}$. This can then lead to: for any two sets $\{w\},\{u,v\}$,we have the set $\{u,v,w\}$, and so on. Hence, we can build *finite* sets using the Pairing Axiom.

My question is: How could $A$, the infinite collection of sets, ever be built using just the pairing axiom? And if it can never be built, how can it be the basis for a new axiom (namely the Union Axiom).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Seventh ZF axiom ("The Axiom of Infinity") posits the existence of an infinite set. This is an axiom.

Comment: @Frank- Thanks! I haven't yet come across this axiom. The book is inconsistent in itss development of theory, I suppose.

Comment: No problem :) Logically it isn't inconsistent (by the sounds of it), because it just says *if* there is an infinite set of sets $A$, *then*... It doesn't actually claim that there does exist such an infinite set $A$. Though without looking at the book I can't say with certainty!

Comment: Though you are right, it is strange to state the Union Axiom in terms of infinite sets. Normally the Union Axiom is stated in terms of the 'union' of just *two* sets (as far as I remember!).

Comment: Given two sets $\{u,v\}$ and $\{w\}$, the **Pairing Axiom** leads to the two-element set $\{\{u,v\},\{w\}\}$ containing the two elements $\{u,v\}$ and $\{w\}$. From there, an application of the **Union Axiom** will get you the three-element set $\{u,v,w\}$.

Comment: Yes, having double checked I apparently do remember wrong :)

Comment: The union axiom is not stated in terms of infinite sets, the motivation was; the axiom itself does not discuss finiteness or not of $A$. Anyway, though I do not know whether Enderton was aware of it, there is a good reason for motivating the axiom in terms of infinite unions: In the presence of the other $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms, the existence of unions of finitely many sets can be proved. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/498990/462).

Answer (score 1):

As Andres Caicedo [put it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720663/a-question-regarding-the-validity-of-the-union-axiom#comment1506700_720663) in the comments:

> The union axiom is not stated in terms of infinite sets, the motivation was; the axiom itself does not discuss finiteness or not of A. Anyway, though I do not know whether Enderton was aware of it, there is a good reason for motivating the axiom in terms of infinite unions: In the presence of the other ZFC axioms, the existence of unions of finitely many sets can be proved. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/498990/462).