# Equivalence of Axiom of Regularity

Tags: set-theory, axioms

So Axiom of regularity states:  every non-empty set A contains an element that is disjoint from A

I'm wondering if this is equivalent as any set is not a member of itself? If so, how do we prove it?

If not, I am wondering is knowing any set is not a member of itself sufficient to derive that a∈b and b∈a cannot be both true?

Answer (score 8):

No, this is not equivalent.

It is consistent that $A\notin A$ for all $A$, but there is $A,B$ such that $A\in B\in A$. The proof is quite difficult, but we can start with a model with atoms, and an extensional relation on the atoms, then realize that relation as $\in$.

With this we can start with two atoms, and the relation will simply be $a\mathrel{E}b\mathrel{E}a$.

---

You can ask whether or not the axiom of regularity is equivalent to just saying that there are no infinite decreasing sequences, and without the axiom of choice this is not true either using the same constructions, only mixing in some counterexamples to the axiom of choice.

Comment: Hi Asaf. Do you have a reference for this? I couldn't locate it (after a not too systematic or extensive search...)

Comment: I have the Hebrew notes of Matti Rubin. I believe this is due to Mostowski. The part about the axiom of choice is a question that came up on the site before, I told him about it and he got interested enough to sit and verify, but I'm not sure if there's any written accounts. I'll try to find something later tonight and let you know.

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice to have an English version of those notes... Related: Was there any luck looking for references for [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498256/can-we-prove-the-existence-of-a-cup-b-without-the-union-axiom/498990#comment1072256_498990)?

Comment: Hey Asaf, can u elaborate a little bit on how to derive a E b E a please?

Comment: @user1819047: You take the theorem that any extensional relation on the atoms can be realized as $\in$, and you take that given $E$.

Comment: @Andres: I think that I couldn't find anything. I'll take another look while I'm at it.

Comment: @Andres: Taking a quick look (since I have to go in a moment), it seems that Felgner's book "Models of ZF set theory" has a chapter about these models. Felgner attributes the consistency of $\lnot\sf Reg$ to Bernays and Specker.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Nice. I'll check the book, every time I do I find something interesting there.

Comment: @Andres: I just checked Matti's homepage, and apparently he rewrote his notes in English when he gave the course two years ago. I'm not a big fan of his writing style (when it comes to lecture notes, anyway), and some of the terms are bad translations of Hebrew terms, which were badly translated from English before.

Comment: Ah, great! (But I failed at finding his page... There seems to be no link from http://www.math.bgu.ac.il/directory/faculty.html, and the guess http://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~mattirubin returns a "Forbidden".)

Comment: @Andres: Without the Rubin part, just `~matti` (you might have to add `www.` at the beginning too) Here's a direct link to the file, might save some time: http://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~matti/Axiomatic-ST-2012-09--Negation-of-Fnd-is-consistent.pdf I'm pretty sure the proof is due to Bernays, at least from the looks of it. But only an examination of his paper (and Specker's habilitation) will give a conclusive answer.

Comment: Ah, excellent! Once again, many thanks.

Comment: @Andres: No problems. I have long contemplated of writing that construction in what I consider a readable form (I always got lost in Matti's notes, we're just too different about that). I might do that over the weekend. I'll let you know how it went.