# Can a weak form of the union axiom be proved in ZF set theory?

Tags: set-theory

I read somewhere that the statement "$x \cup y$ exists for every $x$ and $y$" can be proven in $ZFC$ set theory without using the full strength of the union axiom, which says that arbitrary unions exist, not just binary unions. Can that statement also be proven from $ZF$ set theory? Is this an open problem?

Comment: Can you sketch, or give a reference for, the ZFC proof?  How does it use the axiom of choice?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498256/can-we-prove-the-existence-of-a-cup-b-without-the-union-axiom?rq=1

Comment: @user107952 The post you linked contains a complete answer to your question posted in great detail by Andrés E. Caicedo. Hence I vote to close this question as a duplicate.